# add label on cell in table view and access it on buttonClicked Method.....:)

Tags: iphone, ios

i am a new Programmer.... i wants add two labels on cell in table view.....and access the label.text in buttonClicked method.....

i am new programmer..so i don't know add label on table cell.... is I am right?

thanks in advance...for giving your valuable time for my code....:)

```
 ///insert individual row into the table view

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Cell %i",indexPath.section]];

if (cell == nil) {

    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Cell %i",indexPath.section]] autorelease];

}


cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;//my code.... change the color or selected cell



search_items *pro = [searchCount objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];



   /// i wants access these two labels on buttonClicked Method...


UILabel *showroomName = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:anySize];

[showroomName setText:pro.s_showroomName];

[cell addSubview:showroomName];

[showroomName release];


UILabel *productName = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:anySize];

[productName setText:pro.s_productName];

[cell addSubview:productName];

[productName release];

   UIButton* aButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];

aButton.frame = CGRectMake(150, 15,150,40); 

[aButton setTag:indexPath.row];

    [aButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    [cell.contentView addSubview:aButton];

UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];

    [aButton setImage:img forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [aButton setTitle:@"View Details" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[aButton addSubview:buttonLabel1];


NSString *filepath=[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:pro.s_image ofType:@"png"];

    UIImage *image=[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:filepath];



cell.imageView.image=image;



return cell;

}

-(void)buttonClicked:(UIButton*)sender {

    //int tag = sender.tag;


}
```

Comment: You should state in your question what the code sample you posted actually does -- in other words, did it do something different to what you expected?

Comment: @occulus .. thanks for help..... i wants access my cell labels (showroomName.text and productName.text) on button click...so i fetch the table from database..

Answer (score 2):

```
UILabel *showroomName = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:anySize];

[showroomName setText:pro.s_showroomName];

cell.accessoryView = showroomName;
```

Try this for memory management: Alloc the label in a method that gets called a single time (like `viewDidLoad`, `viewWillAppear`, `viewDidAppear`, `init`, even `numberOfSectionInTableView`) and just change it's text or whatever you want to change in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. This way, you will not have leaks, bad memory management or useless memory allocated. And also, be very careful with realeasing. You should release the objects when you are sure that you won't need those. Some objects might still need them after you release them.