# how to implement textfield in table the way it showing in image

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uitextfield

i want to add textfield on tableview each and access the textfield's text by using their tag.
how can i do that see below image.

[image]

Comment: take a look at this question [which is basically what you want][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7859507/add-label-on-cell-in-table-view-and-access-it-on-buttonclicked-method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

// To get the text from UITextField , add the bellow code to after you initialize the Textfield

```
[yourTextField addTarget:self action:@selector(getTextFieldValue:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingDidEnd];
```

and this method

```
- (void) getTextFieldValue:(UITextField *)textField{
    NSLog(@"GetTextvalue");
    if (textField.tag == 0) {
        NSLog(@"1--->%@",textField.text);
    }else if(textField.tag == 1){
        NSLog(@"2--->%@",textField.text);
    }else if(textField.tag == 2){
        NSLog(@"3--->%@",textField.text);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to customize your tableViewCell you can do that in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method.

While you create your cell in the method you can do following:

```
UITextField *textField = [[UITextField alloc] init];
// Set a unique tag on each text field
textField.tag = 101;
// Add general UITextAttributes if necessary
textField.enablesReturnKeyAutomatically = YES;
textField.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
textField.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeNone;
[cell.contentView addSubview:textField];
[textField release];
```

After that where every you want to access your text field you can do following:

```
UITextField *myTextField = (UITextField*)[cell viewWithTag:yourTag];
```

Hope this is what you are looking for..

**Update**

As you can see I assigned tag 101 as static. This can be any number but make sure that you don't have any other view with the same tag in the same cell. If you have in another cell than its not an issue.

Now at anyplace if lets say in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` you can do following:

```
 UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
 UITextField *myTextField = (UITextFiled*)[cell viewWithTag:101];
```

This way you will get your cell first. Now your cell has only one view with 101 tag so you can get your text field regardless you have same tag for other textField because the cell is not same for all.

Cheers

Comment: UITextField *mytextfield  = (UITextField*)[cell viewWithTag:2];
  NSLog(@"%@",mytextfield.text);  giving null value what should i do

Comment: check my updated answer. In that I assigned a static tag to textField ie. 101. Now you can access it with your cell. Make sure your cell is not null and you are getting your cell

Comment: but i have 10 textfield then how i will access each of them

Comment: Check my updated answer. Let me know if you have still issue and tell me where (in which method) you want to access your textView so I can help you accordingly

Answer (score 1):

```
UITextField *myTextField = (UITextField*)[cell viewWithTag:yourTag];
myTextField.tag=indexPath.row;
```

This way assign 10 textfields tags.
After in textfield delegate method you can retrieve that text from the different 10 tags.